# Initializing JS object from another instance (runtime inheritance)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I want to achieve this:

```
var player = new Player (socket, x, y)
player.on ('event1', function () {});
player.emit ('event2', data);
```

where socket is an instance of Socket supplied externally.

So basically I need to inherit Player from Socket, but initialize it from Socket's instance:

```
var Player = function (socket, x, y)
{
    .....?
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Any idea how I to do it the simplest and the most elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, I assume you've considered but rejected using composition:

```
var Player = function (socket, x, y)
{
    this.socket = socket;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};
```

Usage:

```
var player = new Player(socket, x, y);
player.socket.on(/*...*/);
player.socket.emit(/*...*/);
```

FWIW, I would probably use composition.

But if you don't want to, you have at least a couple of choices:

1. Really inherit, using `socket` as the prototype of the new object:

   In this scenario, you probably wouldn't use `new`:

   ```
   var Player = function (socket, x, y)
   {
       var obj = Object.create(socket);
       obj.x = x;
       obj.y = y;
       return obj;
   };
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   var player = Player (socket, x, y); // No `new` here, although it's harmless
   player.on ('event1', function () {});
   player.emit ('event2', function () {});
   ```

   (Although if you did use `new`, it would be harmless — the object created by `new` would just be thrown away, because `Player` returns a non-`null` object reference, and so overrides the default result of `new`.)

   This won't work if you're relying on the objects inheriting `Player.prototype`, however. You could *copy* everything from `Player.prototype` onto the instance by adding this code to the above:

   ```
   var key;
   for (key in Player.prototype) {
       if (Player.prototype[key] !== Object.prototype[key]) {
           this[key] = Player.prototype[key];
       }
   }
   ```

   That copies any properties from `Player.prototype` (and its prototypes, except for `Object.prototype` as the player will already have those) onto the player object. Less than ideal, but functional, it just means that you need to make sure that `Player.prototype` has everything on it before you create the first player. Also, `instanceof` won't work for players.
2. Just wire up the bits you want, without actually using `socket` as the prototype, by adding bound functions to your `Player` instance that actually route to `socket`:

   ```
   var Player = function (socket, x, y)
   {
       this.on = socket.on.bind(socket);
       this.emit = socket.emit.bind(socket);
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   };
   ```

   Usage is then as in your question, using `new`.

   Or a bit more verbosely, but giving you the opportunity to get in the middle if you needed:

   ```
   var Player = function (socket, x, y)
   {
       this.socket = socket;
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
   };
   Player.prototype.on = function() {
       return this.socket.on.apply(this.socket, arguments);
   };
   Player.prototype.emit = function() {
       return this.socket.emit.apply(this.socket, arguments);
   };
   ```

---

Both of the above use features from ES5 that can be polyfilled. From `Socket`, `on`, and `emit`, I'm guessing you're using NodeJS, and so you're using V8 and you have those features. If not, though, and for others with similar questions: The first solution uses the single-argument version of `Object.create`, the second uses `Function#bind`. If you need to support older JavaScript engines, just look up polyfills for them, both are quite small.

Comment: And also.. 3. Composition: `this.socket = socket;` and then `player.socket.on('event1', function () {}')`. 4. Mixin/extend.

Comment: @dfsq: Indeed. I assumed that the OP had considered and rejected composition, but I should have flagged it up (it would be my first choice). I'll do that. I probably wouldn't use mixin here, too much opportunity for stomping on things as `Socket` is defined by code outside the OP's control.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. The first solution seems to work, but when adding custom functionality through Player.prototype.foo = function () {...} and calling player.foo() it leads to player.foo being undefined! The second solution works flawlessly so I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: I've rejected player.socket.on(...) composition because it looked not that elegant for my taste. I wanted my players to look like they emit and receive events directly.

Comment: @VincentPride: Yeah, I'd *just* added a note about `Player.prototype` to the answer a few minutes before your comment, you might not have seen it. :-) Glad the second option works! :-)

Comment: @VincentPride: FYI, I've added a bit to both options above. Enjoy.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for additional details. I'm using NodeJS indeed, it's intended to be serverside code. Second option is the best, plus it could be extended further, and instanceof would work well.

Answer (score 2):

> So basically I need to inherit Player from Socket

No you don't. Inheritance is an **is-a** relationship and a `Player` is probably not a `Socket`. It probably does on the other hand **use** a `Socket` instance - and that type of relationship can be modelled by a **composite** relationship.

So you need to inject the `Socket` instance into your `Player` constructor for use in the resulting `Player` instance `player`.

What you are attempting to do here is use inheritance for code-reuse and that has been shown over the years to be a flawed approach because of the tight implicit (and usually unwanted) coupling it introduces between parent and child object. Based on the information in your question, composition is the way to go.

Comment: You're right, composition would be more cool in my case, since I'm using only on() and emit(). But imagine having a huge superclass with dozens of methods which you have to rebind in your child class.

Comment: @VincentPride JS doesn't have classes (yet) - although I know what you mean. But the bit about a huge object and rebinding, I don't follow.

Answer (score 0):

The term `inheritance` is different in JS as compared to other languages. Specifically, when many people think of `inheritance`, they think of `classical inheritance` which doesn't exist in JS. Instead, JS uses the concept of *delegation* to prototype objects in order to simulate inheritance-like behavior. Based on what you're describing, it seems like you want instances of `Player` to have functionality that belongs to `Socket`. In that case, what you're describing is more like instances of `Player` delegating to `Socket`.

Here's some example code:

```
// assuming you have code that defines what a socket is
var Player = function (x, y) {
  var socket = new Socket();
  var p = Object.create( socket );
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;

  return p;
};
```

Instances of `Player` will now be able to delegate property lookups to the `socket` instance.

Comment: ECMA-262 4.2.1: "Each constructor is a function that has a property named `prototype` that is used to implement prototype-based inheritance"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder after having read https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes, I'm also of the author's opinion that the term `prototypical inheritance` is a misnomer. In classical inheritance, when a class inherits from another class, those methods and properties are copied over into the new subclass. However, the dynamic is JS is completely different. Properties are looked up on the instance and if not found, the lookup is delegated to the prototype object.

Comment: @wmock: Use of the word "inheritance" with prototypical inheritance is very well-established with something like a 35-year history, long predating JavaScript. Feel free to race against the wind if you like, but I'd keep it out of answers if you're trying to be most useful. :-) *(Not my dv)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think we're both in agreement in terms of how this question should be solved :) Now it's just a matter of whether we both agree with the semantics of the terminology used - to each their own!

Comment: The spec uses the term "prototypical inheritance". I DVd because this means that you need to supply significant evidence to back-up your assertion that "There is no such thing as inheritance in JS". If you said: "There is no such thing as classical inheritance in JS", then fair enough :)

Comment: I agree with you @Ben - I've reworded my answer to better express our comments.